# How can I access the input values of dynamically generated input fields in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-for, input-field, v-model

I am creating a form in vue 3 in which some select fields are dynamically generated using v-for based on the input value of another input field.

So I don't know how I can access the values of each select field since they are generated dynamically and all have the same value.

Please how can I now go about giving them unique v-model values such that I can access each of them individually and use in my scripts data.

I tried concatenating the v-model value of each select field with its element index to make each of them unique but I kept getting errors trying to perform that in the v-model value.

Input field to enter number of subjects below

```
<n-form-item class="input-field-div" label="Number of subjects passed">
        <n-input-number v-model:value="nSubs" placeholder="Number passed" />
</n-form-item>
```

Div element to dynamically generate the select fields based on input field above

```
<div
        v-for="(i, index) in nSubs"
        :key="index"
        class="itemSelect"
        style="display: flex; width: 100%"
>
        <n-select
          style="width: 65%; margin: 0 2% 2% 0"
          v-model:value="value"
          :options="subjects"
        />

        <n-select style="width: 35%" v-model:value="value" :options="grades" />
</div>
```

My script code with options value

```
<script>
import StepsBar from "../components/StepsBar.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedValue: "",
      selectedValues: "",
      value: null,
      selectedOption: null,
      nSubs: 0,
      isActive: false,
      subjects: [
        { label: "Biology (510)", value: "1" },
        { label: "Chemistry (515)", value: "2" },
        { label: "Economics (525)", value: "3" },
        { label: "English Language (530)", value: "4" },
        { label: "French (545)", value: "5" },
        { label: "Geography (550)", value: "6" },
        { label: "Human Biology (565)", value: "7" },
        { label: "Mathematics (570)", value: "8" },
        { label: "Physics (580)", value: "8" },
        { label: "Computer Science (595)", value: "9" },
      ],
      grades: [
        { label: "A", value: "1" },
        { label: "B", value: "2" },
        { label: "C", value: "3" },
        { label: "D", value: "4" },
        { label: "E", value: "5" },
        { label: "F", value: "6" },
        { label: "O", value: "7" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  components: {
    StepsBar,
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way ist to also create a data structure to your input fields.

When you want to store a list of values, then you can use a Array `[]`.

```
<div
        v-for="(i, index) in nSubs"
        :key="index"
        class="itemSelect"
        style="display: flex; width: 100%"
>
        <n-select
          style="width: 65%; margin: 0 2% 2% 0"
          v-model="data[index]"
          :options="subjects"
        />

        <n-select style="width: 35%" v-model:value="value" :options="grades" />
</div>
```

And then init the data field to store the values.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      data: []
      ...
```

Also the syntax you are using here: `v-model:value="value"`
I don't know if this is working

Comment: Alright thanks I'll try that out and let you know if it works.

Comment: Concerning this syntax: v-model:value="value", it is actually the ui framework I'm using and that's how the make use of the v-model in order to access the value. You can check it out it's Naive UI